# Groff images on the same line?

Tags: unix, groff, troff

Is there a way to put images on the same line as each other? I can get them on the same line as text using this code, which creates 2 lines with the 
text on the left and the images on the right, but it's pretty hacky and I still can't get the images on the same line.

```
.PS
circle invisible
"github url"
move right
.PSPIC githublogo.ps 0.3
move left
"linkin url"
.PSPIC linkdinlogo.ps 0.3
.PE
```

None of the pic commands do anything with PSPIC aside from push it to the side, line spacing has no effect, and `man groff_tmac` covers PSPIC but does not give any info on whether it's even possible to do inline images.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the `.mk` and `.rt` requests like so.

```
.mk
.PSPIC -L LEFTIMAGE
.rt
.PSPIC -R RIGHTIMAGE
```

Here `.mk` marks the current vertical position and `.rt` returns to it. the -L and -R position the images to the left and to the right.